# Gstreamer videosink configuration error when playing videos with Parole

Tags: xfce, video-player, gstreamer

I can't play videos with `Parole`. Theres is a `gstreamer` error (`videosink configuration`). I've also installed restricted extras and VLC and i still can't play movies. I've no problem playing audio files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the `"Gstreamer backend error: Configured videosink video is not working."` message, then you can try to run in the command line the following, only once:

```
parole --xv false
```

This solution was suggested in this related Ubuntu forums [gstreamer videosink error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056602) thread.